# Can Pepper robot's head and tablet connect to different SSID?

Tags: wifi, pepper

I used Pepper Robot version 1.8a with NaoQi 2.5.5.5.
As I know the robot's head and tablet have an independent WiFi (both have different mac address). Can I connect the robot's head and tablet to different SSID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you cannot, because tablet's wifi settings will enforce the head's one. The two settings are meant to be synchronized.

However in practice if you can ssh to the robot's head, you should be able to use the [`ALConnectionManager` service](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/connectionmanager/index.html) with [`qicli`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/libqi/guide/qicli.html), and tell the head to connect to a different SSID. This API might still be available locally on Pepper 2.9, but it has no guarantee to be reliable, since Pepper's tablet might override your settings at any time, typically at reboot.